# Hibernate won't remove parent but removes children (or relationship) when it fails to delete parent because of foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have some entities (WarehouseTransactionGroup, WarehouseTransactionAttribute, AttributeValue) with following relationship:

```
@Entity
public class WarehouseTransactionGroup extends MasterEntity {

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @MapKeyColumn
   private Map<WarehouseTransactionAttribute, AttributeValue> attributes;

   // Getter and setter

}
```

When I try to remove a object of type WarehouseTransactionGroup, it naturally fails due to foreign key constraint since the object is used in some other database record. However, Hibernate clears the data in attributes field.

I am calling remove operation, i.e., session.delete() inside a transaction.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You [shouldn't use `CascadeType.ALL` for `@ManyToMany`](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) associations.

1. You need to change the cascade to `CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE`:

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
      @MapKeyColumn
      private Map attributes;
2. The delete goes like this:

   ```
   WarehouseTransactionGroup wtg = ...;
   attributes.clear();
   em.remove(wtg);
   ```